# How should I begin and end an email to an institution (like a Consulate) to request some information?

Tags: salutations

I'm wondering how I should start and end a letter requesting information from a Consulate. Dear Department / Dear Service / Dear Sir/Madam and Yours faithfully?

Comment: Put "Dear Sir" in the search box and top right corner of this page and you will get lots of questions ans answers addressing similar issues. Please browse through those first.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with dear sir/madam or To whomever it may concern

Hope I helped

Comment: Please explain *why*, so as to help the OP understand the usage.