# "Dear Sir (or Madam)" when gender unknown?

Tags: word-choice, letter-writing, salutations

When writing a formal letter addressed to someone whose gender is unknown, how important is it to use "Dear Sir or Madam", instead of "Dear Sir"?

I was taught that "Dear Sir" is an acceptable gender-neutral salutation but times may have changed, is this right or wrong?

Comment: Dear Sir isn't correct if you do not know someone's gender. Also there's good advice here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43608/what-is-the-correct-way-to-greet-a-specific-person-when-only-their-business-titl

Comment: This question probably belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) because it is about communication in everyday English, and is not about the academic study of English Language.

Comment: Related: [“Dear Sir or Madam” versus “To whom it may concern”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2112/43980), [How to address letter to a company](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/89881/43980), [How should I begin and end an email to an institution](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/123466/43980), [Usage of 'Dear All'](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32199/43980), [Official e-mail](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95604/43980), and many more (Search for "Dear Sir").

Comment: Thanks for the links to related questions, but my specific question was whether "Dear Sir" was an acceptable gender-neutral formal salutation. I don't see that specific question being addressed in the related questions.

Comment: From a common sense standpoint, I can say that if I received a letter addressed "Dear Sir", as a woman, I'd probably not think very highly of the sender.  Why risk showing an unknown recipient that you "assume" the recipient of your letter should be a man?  That's not really very PC in this day and age. (FWIW)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dear Sir may have been an acceptable gender-neutral salutation some time ago, but I would suggest 'To whom it may concern,' as a more modern and suitable alternative :)

Answer (score 7):

When the addressee is in the same field as the writer, you can use the address ***Dear Colleague***.

Comment: I like that; hadn't thought of it before.

Comment: Don't you find that it always rains when you try to write a letter in a field?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, because I am not a man out standing in his field.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to begin a formal letter to someone whose gender is unknown is with the "Dear Sir/Madam," phrase while At the end the letter use the phrase "Yours faithfully," plus your full name, like the template that follows:

Dear Sir/Madam,

....

Yours faithfully,
Your full name

Comment: Might offend someone going through a sex change.